# Creating a web form via an es6 script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to use es6 webpage to create a webpage with just an email form on it. The form has 3 fields(Name, email, subject), a text box to type the message, and a button to send the message. The button links to a php script that sends the email(I may change this so javascript sends the email with react, but I'm moving slowly and already had the php)

This is a plain html file that would do the same thing. So the expected output, should look like the output from this file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="form_style form_class" data-state="desktop left" data-dcf-columns="4">
        <form action="/php/email_me.php" method="post" role="form" aria-label="contact form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div>
            <input id="field1" aria-invalid="false" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Name" data-aid="nameField" type="text">
            <input id="field2" aria-invalid="false" name="Email" value="" placeholder="Email" data-aid="emailField" type="text">
            <input id="field3" aria-invalid="false" name="Subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" data-aid="subjectField" type="text">
          </div>
          <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" data-aid="messageField" ></textarea>
          <button style="background-color:#014391" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>                           
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the corresponding HTML with embedded jsx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id='emailForm' class="form_style form_class" data-state="desktop left" data-dcf-columns="4"></div>
      <script>
        var Wrapper = (props) => {
          return (
            <div className="form_style form_class" data-state="desktop left" data-dcf-columns="4">
                <form action="/php/email_me.php" method="post" role="form" aria-label="contact form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div>
                        <Field id='field1' name='Name' dataAid='nameField'  />
                  <Field id='field2' name='Email' dataAid='emailField'  />
                  <Field id='field3' name='Subject' dataAid='subjectField'  />
                    </div>
                  <textarea name="Message" className="message" placeholder="Message" data-aid="messageField"></textarea>
                  <button style="background-color:#014391" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>                           
                </form>
            </div>
            )
          }

          var Field = (props) => {
            return (
            <input id={props.id} aria-invalid="false" name={props.name} value="" placeholder={props.name} data-aid={props.dataAid} type={props.type}></input>
            )
          }
          Field.defaultProps = { type: 'text'}

          ReactDOM.render(
            <Wrapper />,
            document.getElementById('emailForm')
          )
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**temp.css**

```
.form_class {
    top: 20px;
    width: 780px;
    position: relative;
    height: 316px;
    margin: auto;
}

.form_style input,.form_style textarea {
    font:normal normal normal 16px/1.875em raleway,sans-serif ;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;border:1px solid rgba(11, 50, 89, 1);
    color:#0B3259;
    margin:0 0 5px;
    width:100%;
}

/* Send button */
.form_style button {
    background-color:rgba(11, 50, 89, 1);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: JSX code must be transpiled with babel in order to work, when you include it this way in a html file that's not possible (I think at least it's not). You should extract that to a separate file and add babel etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Goran.it was correct that you *should* make a separate file and transpile it, but you don't *have* to. Based on the fact that you are adding a `<script>` tag for babel, I think you meant to transpile the script on the webpage. Just add a `type="text/babel"` to your script tag.

There were a other minor errors in your code, namely that `style` has to be passed an object and not a string, and `enctype` should be `encType`. Here's your entire script tag with these changes:

```html
<script type="text/babel">
  var Wrapper = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="form_style form_class" data-state="desktop left" data-dcf-columns="4">
        <form action="/php/email_me.php" method="post" role="form" aria-label="contact form" encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
              <Field id='field1' name='Name' dataAid='nameField'  />
              <Field id='field2' name='Email' dataAid='emailField'  />
              <Field id='field3' name='Subject' dataAid='subjectField'  />
            </div>
          <textarea name="Message" className="message" placeholder="Message" data-aid="messageField"></textarea>
          <button style={{backgroundColor: "#014391"}} type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>                           
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  var Field = (props) => {
    return (
      <input id={props.id} aria-invalid="false" name={props.name} value="" placeholder={props.name} data-aid={props.dataAid} type={props.type}></input>
    )
  }
  Field.defaultProps = { type: 'text' }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Wrapper />,
    document.getElementById('emailForm')
  )
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it that style has to be passed an object? What can that be universalized to. Is it just that style always has to be passed an object in jsx?

Comment: @Jacob Styles always have to be an object, according to [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style). I'm not sure why they decided this — the documentation says something vague about preventing cross site scripting.